# Multisig with existing single sig + passphrase

Tags: multi-signature, hardware-wallet, passphrase

If I take 2 brand new HW wallets (like a Coldcards), plus an *existing* hw single sig wallet that has a passphrase and finds already assigned to it (like a Trezor)and then create a new multisig 2 of 3 set up, will the passphrase be required to use the existing Wallet within the multisig (to send, for instance)?

If I don’t want the passphrase to be required, but have funds on the existing wallet already, how would I go about moving the funds and creating the multisig with these 3 wallets, where no passphrase is required for that existing wallet?

Hope this is clear and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> will the passphrase be required to use the existing Wallet within the multisig (to send, for instance)?

If you don't choose to sign with the Trezor's key, then no. Given that you have 2 master private keys out of the total 3, you don't have to access the Trezor one, and thus, no need to type the passphrase. However, if you want to spend using a signature from Trezor, you'll need the passphrase, because master private keys with a passphrase aren't stored in the device.

Quoting [wiki.trezor.io/Passphrase](https://wiki.trezor.io/Passphrase):

> **The passphrase is not stored anywhere on the device.** It is only used temporarily whenever you enter it.

> If I don’t want the passphrase to be required, but have funds on the existing wallet already, how would I go about moving the funds and creating the multisig with these 3 wallets, where no passphrase is required for that existing wallet?

Not sure I understand what you mean here. If you want to move funds from your 2-of-3 multi-sig (with the passphrase) to a 2-of-3 multi-sig (without the passphrase) you don't need to access the Trezor, as I've said above.

Comment: Sorry if I’m not being clear. 

How can I use the single sig + passphrase in multisig, but not require the paraphrase when using that wallet doing MS transactions (only use when doing single sig)?  Or is this not possible to exclude existing passphrase from multisig if it’s part of the existing wallet? Thx

Comment: And I mean use for signing transactions.

Comment: Again, if you want to sign from the 2-of-3 multi-sig, you need 2 out of 3 signatures. If one of them has to come from Trezor, you need to type the passphrase.

Comment: Got it. So pasphrase has to be included if it was part of the original set up. 

However, when it was set up, there is an “account” from just the 12 word seed, and the one that has the added passphrase. 

How can I get the non passphrase account to be used in the MS set up and not the passphrase one (if possible)?